# Only numbers get inserted in sql

Tags: php, sql, forms

So i have this form

```
<form>Tag name:
    <input type='text' name='tagname' />
    <input type='submit' value='Add' />
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' />
</form>
<hr />
```

it runs this script

```
if ($tagname) 
{   
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES ($id, $tagname)");
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Tag added.");
    history.back();
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

If i insert numbers in form it gets added to sql database nicely,but if it consist of alphabetical characters i get the alert but nothing is inserted in database.
I checked phpmyadmin if the structure is wrong(text/varchar/int...) tried most of them but it is the same.

Comment: ty all the quotes worked,there is a lot of security issues but that is whole new question :/ it will work for localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need single quotes to enclose strings within SQL queries:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES ('$id', '$tagname')");
```

And I'm conjecturing you also forgot to apply [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES ($id, '$tagname')");
```

Very common mistake. Think about escaping, or better - parametrizing queries. Concatenating an SQL query is an awful approach (so is putting in a small piece of code, together, HTML, PHP, SQL and JavaScript)

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around $id (unless it's a number) and $tagname in your mysql query.

As a side note, this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of issues with your code, first setting the value for the id input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

And then, in the SQL you should use quotes:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES ($id, '$tagname')");
```

Answer (score 1):

In so far as I can tell based on your code, and depending on how you're escaping, if you've no ajax to fetch the id you're running either of:

```
INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES (0, $tag)
INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES ('', $tag)
```

You should really be running:

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ('$tag')
```